# Troubleshoot connecting to free trial postgres on AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql, connection, psycopg2, pgadmin-4

This is a temporary database, so I don't mind sharing credentials. We have setup the following in RDS:

**Host and Port and confirming public access**

[image]

**DB Name**

[image]

Not shown is the username and password, however I am 100% certain that we are inputting the correct username and password into PgAdmin 4 and into python's `psycopg2.connect` function.

**Failing connection in PgAdmin 4**

[image]

However, we are failing to connect in both PgAdmin 4 and in python. The database is definitely public, and I am fairly certain that we are inputting the correct parameters. I believe **dbname** is `testdb` and not the instance ID `etl-test`

What could be the issue? The one thing I am not certain about are the VPCs and the VPC security groups... do we need to input these anywhere into python or PgAdmin4 in order to connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not the issue with pg-Admin or python. Looks like you don't have proper inbound rules set up.
[this](https://serverfault.com/questions/1011144/aws-rds-to-pgadmin-error-saving-properties-unable-to-connect-to-server-timeout/1011181#1011181) blog post might interests you